# AppleScript and Music

Tags: applescript, music.app

I have created a small AppleScript that queries Music App if it is playing, and if it is then it queries and gets artist and song name. Now I want to query some more information.

Where can I find the documentation regarding the available commands and information that I can use from Music app? For example, I now use something like:

```bsh
set a to "Now playing: " & artist of current track & " - " & name of current track
```

what else can I use except `artist of current track` or `name of current track`? Where can I find what other information can I query/use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where can I find what other information can I query/use?

Check out the **Library** in **Script Editor**.

**Script Editor** > **Window** > **Library    ⇧⌘L**

You can also query the `properties` of the `current track` to see what else is available specifically to it, e.g.:

```applescript
tell application "Music" to get properties of current track
```

On my system at the moment, it returns:

```applescript
{class:file track, id:181, index:8, name:"Brain Damage", persistent ID:"C2EE4E8E7AD4C9A6", database ID:157, date added:date "Saturday, November 21, 2020 at 3:59:39 AM", time:"3:50", duration:230.757995605469, artist:"Pink Floyd", album artist:"", composer:"Roger Waters", album:"Dark Side Of The Moon", genre:"Rock", bit rate:192, sample rate:44100, track count:9, track number:8, disc count:1, disc number:1, size:5595268, volume adjustment:0, year:1973, comment:"", EQ:"", kind:"AAC audio file", media kind:song, modification date:date "Tuesday, September 6, 2005 at 1:08:28 PM", enabled:true, start:0.0, finish:230.757995605469, played count:1, skipped count:0, compilation:false, rating:0, bpm:0, grouping:"", bookmarkable:false, bookmark:0.0, shufflable:true, lyrics:"", category:"", description:"", episode number:0, unplayed:true, sort name:"", sort album:"", sort artist:"", sort composer:"", sort album artist:"", loved:false, disliked:false, album loved:false, album disliked:false, cloud status:unknown, work:"", movement:"", movement number:0, movement count:0, location:alias "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Music:Music:Media.localized:Pink Floyd:Dark Side Of The Moon:08 Brain Damage.m4a"}
```

---

Also have a look at: [About Scripting Terminology](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AboutScriptingTerminology.html):

> The terminology for an app is found in its *scripting dictionary*, an
> .sdef file stored in the app bundle. The dictionary describes the
> commands, classes, and properties an app supports. This information is
> used by the scripting components of the operating system, the app
> itself, and any other apps or scripts that interact with the app
> through scripting. It also serves as a reference, which you can
> consult in Script Editor for guidance as you write a script. See
> Figure 10-1.
>
> **Figure 10-1Example of a scripting dictionary in Script Editor**
>
> [image]

Comment: Yes, but this dictionary shows nothing about specific applications. This is just generic AppleScript stuff, which I already have found. Unless I’m missing something.

Comment: I’m explicitly asking about what else I can use from Music app, apart `artist of current track` or `name of current track`. Where is this information at the library that you indicate?

Comment: @Xxxo, See updated answer.

Comment: Thnx! I will also check the other things that you mention.

Comment: When I run `tell application "Music" to get properties of current track` in the script editor I get `error "Music got an error: Can’t get properties of current track." number -1728 from properties of current track`

Comment: @Brian, From the **AppleScript** _dictionary_ for **Music**: **track** _n_ [inh. item] : playable audio source, and **current track** (track, r/o) : the current targeted track -- So I'd expect you to get that error if there is no track currently paused/playing in **Music**. The OP did state "if it is playing" in its first sentence. So, did you have a track paused/playing in **Music** when you ran that **AppleScript** _code_? If not, then that's why you'd get that error message.

Comment: @user3439894 I am seeing this message when a track is playing as well as when the track is paused, but I also think I should move this issue to a new question.

Comment: update: it was a permissions issue :)

Comment: @Brian Could you share how you solve the permission issue? Thanks.

Comment: @Fenjin_Wang it worked that day and now it's not. I created a new question focused on this issue at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412646/unable-to-read-object-properties-with-applescript-music-got-an-error-can-t-ge